# Karma+Angular: How do I access a same-name function in two js files?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I'm trying to unit test a particular function in "validation.js". There are identical function names present in "changepassword.js". This means that when I call the function I want to test, it chooses to execute "changepassword"'s function instead of "validation"'s function. The kicker is that there is no module name associated with validation, so I'm not sure how to pinpoint that method for testing.

Here's my question:

## How do I tell karma to call `validation.js`'s function INSTEAD of `changepassword.js`'s function?

---

### validation.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {      

function ispassWordValid(){
    var password = $(".loginPWD").val();
    if(password.length <=7){
        return false;
    }else{
        return true;
    }
}

});
```

### changepassword.js (Exactly the same)

```
$(document).ready(function() {      

function ispassWordValid(){
    var password = $(".loginPWD").val();
    if(password.length <=7){
        return false;
    }else{
        return true;
    }
}

});
```

### Karma configuration

This is configured to **preload all HTML files into templates** using [karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor).

```
module.exports = function(config) {
  'use strict';

  config.set({
    autoWatch: true,
    basePath: '../',
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],
    files: [
      'app/**/*.js',
      'app/**/*.html' //For karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor
    ],
    port: 8080,
    browsers: [
      'PhantomJS'
    ],
    plugins: [
      'karma-phantomjs-launcher',
      'karma-jasmine',
      'karma-spec-reporter',
      'karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor',
      'karma-coverage'
    ],
    reporters: ['spec','coverage'],
    preprocessors: {
      'app/**/*.html': ['ng-html2js'],
      'app/**/**/*.js': 'coverage'
    },
    ngHtml2JsPreprocessor: {
    stripPrefix: 'app/',
        moduleName: 'queueManagerApp-testTemplates'
    },
  });
};
```

Now I am able to access these preloaded templates in my unit test my using `module('queueManagerApp','queueManagerApp-testTemplates' )`

### Unit Test

This is where it is failing. I want to access validation.js's `ispassWordValid` function, and NOT changepassword's `ispassWordValid`. **How do I specify `validation.js's ispassWordValid` function**?

```
'use strict';

describe('test/spec/controllers/validation.js - No controller', function () {


describe('password validation', function () {
     it('should be true for valid passwords', function() {
         spyOn($.fn, "val").and.returnValue("goodpassword"); 
         var result = ispassWordValid(); //<--- this is calling changepassword.js and not validation.js!
         expect(result).toEqual(true); 
     });
     it('should fail for invalid passwords', function() {   
         spyOn($.fn, "val").and.returnValue(""); 
         var result = ispassWordValid(); //<--- this is calling changepassword.js and not validation.js!
         expect(result).toEqual(false);
     });
});

});
```

### Attempts

Here are my attempts, all failed:

- `beforeEach(module('app/scripts/controllers/validation.js' ));`
- `beforeEach(module('scripts/controllers/validation.js' ));`
- `beforeEach(module('/scripts/controllers/validation.js' ));`
- `beforeEach(module('queueManagerApp','queueManagerApp-testTemplates' ));`
- `beforeEach(module('queueManagerApp','queueManagerApp-testTemplates','validation'  ));`
- `beforeEach(module('queueManagerApp','queueManagerApp-testTemplates','app/scripts/controllers/validation.js'  ));`
- `beforeEach(module('queueManagerApp','queueManagerApp-testTemplates','app/scripts/controllers/validation'  ));`

Any ideas?

Comment: downvoted with no comments or replies :(

Comment: now the question got upvoted :)

Comment: Yesss ty @EL3PHANTEN! That downvote affected me more than it should've lol :)